# Add Loader/Spinner at center of a button

Tags: css

I want to add a spinner at the center of my button using CSS.The spinner should load at the center everytime the width of button changes. If i set margins the spinner position remains same and it does not change with the button text and does not align to center.
[My Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARpBv.jpg)
[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0sND.jpg)

```css
.ic2-fa-spin-blue {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    border: 3px solid #008ad6;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-top: 3px solid #f3f3f3;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    -webkit-animation: ic2-spin 2s linear infinite; /* Safari */
    animation: ic2-spin 2s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: ic2-spin 2s infinite linear;
    -o-animation: ic2-spin 2s infinite linear;
    /*position: absolute;
    /*margin-left:1em;*/
    /*margin-top: 6px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;*/
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
@-webkit-keyframes ic2-spin {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@keyframes ic2-spin {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}



.ic2-outlined-spin-blue-btn {
    color: #a3deff;
    border: 1px solid #008ad6;
   
}
.ic2-outlined-btn {
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: var(--white-color);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 500;
    /*line-height: 32px;*/
    text-align: var(--button-alignment);
    padding: 0px 16px;
    border-radius: 3px;    
    width: auto;
    word-spacing: 8px;
    height:32px;
}
```

```html
<button value="Loading" class="ic2-outlined-btn ic2-outlined-spin-blue-btn ">
  <span class=" ic2-fa-spin-blue"></span>
  Loading
</button>
```

I want the spinner to load at center .

Comment: did y try put loading text inside the span tag? instead of outside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can position the spinner using `top: calc(50% - 13px); left: calc(50% - 13px);`. The 50% is measured from the parent, and 13px since the width/height of the spinner is `20px` and border adds `6px` to a total of `26px`, and half of it is `13px`.

Also set `position: relative` on the button `.ic2-outlined-spin-blue-btn`, so it will be the positioning context (the parent).

```css
.ic2-fa-spin-blue {
  border: 3px solid #008ad6;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 3px solid #f3f3f3;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 13px);
  left: calc(50% - 13px);
  animation: ic2-spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes ic2-spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.ic2-outlined-spin-blue-btn {
  position: relative;
  color: #a3deff;
  border: 1px solid #008ad6;
}

.ic2-outlined-btn {
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: var(--white-color);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 500;
  /*line-height: 32px;*/
  text-align: var(--button-alignment);
  padding: 0px 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: auto;
  word-spacing: 8px;
  height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<button value="Loading" class="ic2-outlined-btn ic2-outlined-spin-blue-btn ">
  <span class=" ic2-fa-spin-blue"></span>
  Loading
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `position:relative` to `.ic2-outlined-btn` class.
2. Add this style to `.ic2-fa-spin-blue` class.

```css
right: calc(50% - 15px);
top: 2px;
```